# How can i parse InnerText of <option> tag with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

**Context:**

I am trying to parse the "Cities" from this [Page here](http://www.telelistas.net/). I already managed to simulate the request for the data of this combobox, which is a Ajax call.

Fiddler Request :

```
POST http://www.telelistas.net/AjaxHandler.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.telelistas.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 106
Origin: http://www.telelistas.net
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)      Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.telelistas.net/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: cert_Origin=directo; email=bdc.testes@gmail.com; auto=automatico=0; searchparameters=bottom=0&btnsite=0&email=&uf=rj&origem=0&nome=&pagina=1&codlogradouro=&predio=213&tiquete=0&localidadeendmap=&codbairro=0&pcount=25&estacionamento=0&letra=&top=&entrega=0&pchave=&info=&logradouro=rua+da+lapa&codtitulo=-1&chave=&zoom=&comercial=0&ddd=0&comib=0&btnemail=0&pgresultado=&localidade=&telefone=&manobrista=0&codlocalidade=21000&site=&cartoes=0&atividade=&bairro=&reserva=0&residencial=0; perfil=logged=1&iduser=2563063&email=bdc.testes@gmail.com&usertype=2&specialsearch=3&siteusernome=BigDataCorp&siteuserdatanasc=15/01/1988&siteusersexo=M&siteuserlocalidade=21000&siteuseruf=RJ&siteuserddd=21&siteusertelefone=94118439&siteuserprofissao=4&siteuserrenda=5000&siteuserformacao=4&siteusernovidades=0&siteusernovidadesrevista=&siteusernovidadesparceiros=0&siteusercpf=10541308769&siteuseracesso=brasil&siteusercep=22631000&siteuseridade=24&siteuserparceiro=telelistas&siteuserconhecimento=2&siteuseroperadora=oi&siteuserurlorigem=http://www.telelistas.net/&siteuserdatacadastro=13/12/2012 11:45:00; __utma=70879631.392027796.1355939587.1356014801.1356021821.5; __utmb=70879631.1.10.1356021821; __utmc=70879631; __utmz=70879631.1355939587.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

PostData : state=rj&style=busca_interna&selectedCity=21000&clientId=pch_localidade_select&method=GetSearchCitiesNamed
```

**Issue:**

Here is a fragment of the string returned by this request :

```
<select name='pch_localidade_select' class='busca_interna' id='pch_localidade_select' tabindex="4"><option value="">Selecione</option><option selected value="21000">Rio de Janeiro</option><option value="21380">Abraão</option><option value="21001">Afonso Arinos</option><option value="21002">Agência Luterback</option><option value="21847">Agriões de Dentro</option>
```

What i am trying to do, is to reach the `InnerText`of the Option tags ("Rio de Janeiro", "Abraao"...), but for some weird reason, the `InnerText` is always empty, for every option node found.

There's some code fragment that is failing :

```
        // Iterating over nodes to build the dictionary
        foreach (HtmlNode city in citiesNodes)
        {
            string key   = city.InnerText;
            string value = city.Attributes["value"].Value;

            citiesHash.AddCity (key,value);
        }
```

**Technology in Place:**

I am using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhtmlagilitypack.codeplex.com%2F&ei=cEfTUNTlMu6x0QHWtICoBA&usg=AFQjCNG2MH29eft1y8OrwFMjVzPNbVc0-w&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ) that supports [XPath](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fxpath%2Fxpath_syntax.asp&ei=rEfTUKK-H4Pq0gHrrYGoBg&usg=AFQjCNH9Kx-zvpPSNk_PZUYsxk9ZsupJEg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ) syntax for node selecting, C# code and [Fiddler2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiddler2.com%2F&ei=k0fTUN6mAuXD0QGQkYCICg&usg=AFQjCNGyVxcKeoiBFf3LsfsM8apoKVxKLQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ) for WebDebugging.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some weird reason, HtmlAgilityPack does not handles those  tags correctly, so this managed to solve my problem.

```
        // Iterating over nodes to build the dictionary
        foreach (HtmlNode city in citiesNodes)
        {
            if (city.NextSibling != null)
            {
                string key   = city.NextSibling.InnerText;
                string value = city.Attributes["value"].Value;

                citiesHash.AddCity (key,value);
            }
        }
```

Instead of reaching directly the node,i managed to get the values of each node by using the `NextSimbling` reference from the previous simbling.

Answer (score 14):

Just use `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");` before loading html

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var options = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("option").Skip(1)
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
                    Text = n.InnerText
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This also worked for me, should i delete my answer or leave both options for future use of the community?

Comment: I would leave it, but sometimes people unnecessarily downvotes the answers. So it is your choise.